# Eclipse text editor resizing

Tags: eclipse, resize, mouseevent

How to resize editor pane in Eclipse smoothly? Right now when I resize it - it jumps for about 40 text characters. Other views that are on the left side (Navigator, Task List) are being resized smoothly.

I hope I've explained it right, I am unable to attach screenshots right now...

**Eclipse Kepler SR2**

**Gentoo Linux x64, kernel 3.12.13**

**UPD:** [captured video](http://youtu.be/7rAZVeWX7Po) for better understanding of my problem

Comment: You can share screen shots here http://imgur.com/.

Comment: My Ant pane on the left side also had this problem of not resizing smoothly, and instead snapping to a width that was too large.  The containerData fix mentioned below solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally this would indicate that for the sash having the issues the total of the combined children's 'containerData' is some small integer. I'm not sure how you got into that state though, the sash renderer takes pains to maintain the initial 'total' weight which starts at 10,000.

If you can find the MArea in the model it should have a MPartSashContainer as its child. Open its children and examine the 'containerData' field for each (they should be strings representing ints). If the total of the two containerData values is small then changing the values to 5000 for each child should fix the sizing issues...

Comment: Happens to me the same. Twice with months in between. In just a moment, doing nothing, PUF!, it starts behaving wrong. The fist time I deleted the workspace :P. Your solution works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue with resizing editor windows *vertically* with GGTS 3.4.0 (which is based on Eclipse).  I fixed it via the following steps:

1. Close Eclipse/GGTS
2. Open `workbench.xmi` in a text editor.  The file is located in your workspace's plugins folder (in my case, `workspace\ggts-3.4.0.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench`)
3. Search for all lines containing the text `containerData`
4. If any of the matches contain very low numbers (e.g. `containerData="1"` or `containerData="2"`) change the values to `2500`.  In my case, there were two such entries: one had `type="advanced:Placeholder"` with `elementId="org.eclipse.ui.editorss"` and the other had `type="basic:PartStack"` with `elementId="bottom"`.
5. Save the changes to `workbench.xmi`
6. Open Eclipse/GGTS

Answer (score 0):

Use [Multi drag shash](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.2.2-201302041200/news/eclipse-news-part1.html). You can place the cursor at the intersection of two or more sashes and drag them all at the same time. When you place cursor at this position it changes to hand symbol.

Refer [Split editor short cut key](http://blog.vogella.com/2013/12/12/split-editor-implemented-in-eclipse-m4-luna-solves-bug-8009-one-of-the-highest-voted-bug-in-eclipse-platform/). Plugins [One-click editor splitting in Eclipse](http://sandipchitale.blogspot.in/2011/03/one-click-editor-splitting-in-eclipse.html)  and [Handy Split](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/handysplit#.U3xnc3KoJk8)

Comment: It moves smoothly when dragged vertically, but jumps huge leaps when dragged horizontally. I noticed that thing is related only to the editor. Other views are dragged smoothly horizontally and vertically

Comment: Using the same eclipse version. Its working fine on `Ubuntu 13.10 Gnome classic`. Verify changing the desktop environment. to Gnome/Gnome classic. Are you using KDE?Which version of Gentoo Linux

Comment: Tried changing to Default and GTK themes. No changes

Comment: I've added video capture

Comment: I have got this exact issue too in windows 7, kepler SR2

Comment: Its working for me. If it is not working for you then log bug here http://bugs.eclipse.org/